# print lines with unique specified fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, uniq

How to print lines based on having unique fields `2`, `3` and `4`?

fields number 2 and 3 are numbers and field three is alphabet with total 2500 rows in a file.

**Input:**

```
10,11,12,A,3
10,11,12,A,4
10,11,12,B,3
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
10,11,12,B,3
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
 awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ dup[$2, $3, $4]++; next } (dup[$2, $3, $4]==1)' infile infile
```

Here, we are processing input `infile` two times, first read the file and saving each duplicated lines according to the specified fields `$2`, `$3` and `$4` into the associated array named `dup`; the `++` is incrementing those lines occurrences every time.

At next process, checking and will print the entire line if the specified fields occurred only once.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
egrep '^[^,]*,11,12,B,' input.file
```

Explain:

`^` from begining of the line

`[^,]` anything what is not the ','

`*` as many times as possible

`,11,12,B,` that what you search for

Comment: field 2 and 3 are not static numbers.

Comment: Well, all lines, where patern formed with (field 2, field 3, field 4) are repeated only once? If so, the `awk` is the right solution. (as αғsнιη wrote)